SQL returning on values that do not exist
Sorry i am new to SQL and was wondering if there exists a means to returns a default value for record that do not exist. e.g. select * from tables where col1 in (1,2,3) in this case 2 does not exists in the table



col1
fruit




1
apples


3
bananas


2
sorry this value does not exist in the table




Note that tables have rows, not records.

The general pattern you would follow here would be an anti-join, where you start with a set (table) of all IDs, and then left join to your table above.  In lieu of a formal table, we can use an inline CTE for the former source of IDs table.
WITH ids AS (
    SELECT 1 AS col1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
)

SELECT
    t1.col1,
    COALESCE(t2.fruit, 'sorry this value does not exist in the table') AS fruit
FROM ids t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.col1 = t1.col1;


The result which you wanted is not feasible.
but you can get the count for each of the ID in the col1
Let say If you have below data in to the table name Fruits and you want a count for each of the id and where there is no id exists that will return 0.


Id  FruitName
1   apples
3   bananas
1   apples
3   bananas
1   apples



You can write query like below.
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS CountApples
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS CountBananas
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS CountNull
FROM Fruits

Then It will give the result as below


CountApples CountBananas CountNull
-----------------------------------
3           2            0



I guess you understand.

Of course, it is feasible, see this answer

I was certain there of the answer.
